# Divide 2 numbers and see if the first one divides the second number evenly

Tags: java, modulus, divide

I need to create a program that reads 2 integers from the keyboard and prints a message saying whether the first number divides the second evenly.

I know I have to use either / or %, but it's not working.

```
int y, x,z;

System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
x= keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
y= keyboard.nextInt();
z=y/x;
if (z%2==0){
    System.out.println("Divides evenly");
} else {
    System.out.println("Does not divide evenly");
}
```

I have to divide y by x. So, for example, x= 25 y=100, it should come out even. Then x=35 y=100 not even.

I've tried

```
 z==0

 z%y==0
```

Not working.

Comment: `z%2==0` doesn't say "y divides x evenly", it says "z is even". The variables `x` and `y` should be used *together* with `%`.

Comment: "but it's not working" - is not a problem description. You have 2 basic problems: divides evenly is not the same as % 2 == 0.

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you don't need the extra integer division.

Integer division ( `%` ) gives you the remainder.  So when you do `z=y%x;`, all you need to do in your `if` statement is check that `z` is equal to `0` (meaning that the first number evenly decided the second number).

```
int y, x,z;

System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
x= keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
y= keyboard.nextInt();
z=y%x;
if (z==0){  //Changed this liine
    System.out.println("Divides evenly");
} else {
    System.out.println("Does not divide evenly");
}
```

Comment: Rather than just giving the solution, how about explaining both the problem and the solution so the answer is useful to future visitors? e.g. `11 / 3 => 3` (why?) and `11 % 3 => 2` (again, why?)

Answer (score 1):

```
    int x,y;

    System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
    x= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
    y= keyboard.nextInt();

    if (x%y==0){
    System.out.println("Divides evenly");
    } else {
    System.out.println("Does not divide evenly");
    }
```